# How to include a collection from a derived object in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sorry, that title wasn't great. Say I have some classes:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person {
    public Student() {
        Grades = new List<Grades>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Grades> Grades { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person {
    public string Class { get; set; }
}
public class Grades {
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

This is all mapped up correctly using Entity Framework and I can do:

```
using (var db = new DataContext()) {
    foreach (var student in db.People.where(p => p is Student))
        Console.WriteLine(student.ID);
}
```

But how can I do:

```
db.People.where(p => p is Student).Include(s => s.Grades)
```

Without turning lazyloading on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OfType to filter by type and then apply an Include on it.

```
var students = db.People.OfType<Student>().Include(s => s.Grades);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just mark the Grades property non -virtual (remove the virtual keyword) to disable lazy loading for that .